# Does it make sense to "regress out on one variable" during permutation testing?

Tags: permutation-test, controlling-for-a-variable

In our lab we have developed a non parametric permutation test which assesses whether a feature $f:G\to \mathbb{R}$ respects a given symmetric binary relation $A\subset G\times G$.

Regard $A$ as being equipped with the uniform distribution (except for points on the diagonal, which are discarded). Then $f(A_1),f(A_2)$ are random variables. Write $c(f)$ for the Pearson correlation coefficient of $f(A_1,A_2)$.
Now randomly choose $N$ permutations $\pi$ of $G$ and compute $c(f\circ\pi)$ for each $\pi$. If $c(f)$ lies in the top 5% of the distribution, reject the null hypothesis that $f$ is independent of $A$.

This makes sense to me but my PI  says we can extend this permutation test to handle covariates. Given two features $f, g$ on $G$, plot $(c(f\circ\pi), c(g\circ\pi))$ for $N$ randomly chosen permutations $\pi$, and draw a line of best fit. If the residual $c(f) - \widehat{c(f)}$ is in the upper 5% of residuals, we conclude that $f$ still respects $A$ after accounting for/controlling for $g$.

I am not convinced that this is an appropriate way of controlling for $g$ or "regressing out" $g$. I don't understand why it makes sense to draw a line of best fit through this scatter plot and interpret the residuals. I am unable to interpret this. He claims that this technique is standard.

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understand the setup here (at least not yet). What is the exchangeable quantity in this test?

Comment: In the version with one feature f, the exchangeable quantity is the test statistic c(f). In the version with two features I don't know if there is one? It is not really a permutation test in itself. It's more like regressing out one permutation test by the results of another. The statistic c(f) - \hat{c(f)} can't be known before we sample from the permutation distribution

Comment: It looks like the intent is to use come form of residual as the exchangeable quantity (I wanted to be sure that was the case); naturally they aren't actually exchangeable. At best a suitably scaled residual might (arguably) be asymptotically exchangeable. If sample sizes are not too small it may in some situations be quite reasonable in practice, though (e.g. significance levels not too far from selected significance levels).